# Wordpress category based search

Tags: php, wordpress

Normal search is working fine, but I need to search  based on  category in wordpress.
For eg..
 say  I have two category named as 'Car' and 'Bus', if I choose CAR category then search should display results form CAR category and if I have choose BUS category then search should display results from Bus category.

As of now am using this code

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_all='.__('All Categories',        'appthemes').'&hierarchical='.get_option('cp_cat_hierarchy').'&hide_empty='.get_option('cp_    cat_hide_empty').'&depth='.get_option('cp_search_depth').'&show_count='.get_option('cp_cat_    count').'&pad_counts='.get_option('cp_cat_count').'&orderby=name&title_li=&use_desc_for_tit    le=1&tab_index=2&name=scat&selected='.cp_get_search_catid().'&class=searchbar&taxonomy='.AP    P_TAX_CAT); ?>
```

This code am using in Classipress Theme

Thanks
Shobhit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to  achive this  you have to  replace the standard WordPress search form in searchform.php  with the code below .

This will enable search based on categories .

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>">
<div>
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
<input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" /> 
in <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_all=All Categories' ); ?> 
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</div>
</form>
```